# How to import a library with full dependencies in Choregraphe

Tags: python, http-post, nao-robot, choregraphe

I am working with choregraph to develop an application for Nao robot. 
I am trying to install a library that implements a speech to text functionality: it uses a simple HTTPS request. 
I am not able to make it work because it has a lot of dependencies and choregraph doesn't have a tool to import them properly. 
So my question is: how can I install any HTTPS library on choregraph without downloading every single dependency module of the library?

I would like to make it work also in the virtual robot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to bring external Python modules is to embed them in your Choregraphe project and to append the path to those modules to the `PYTHONPATH`, from inside your behavior. You will be then able to import your external modules.

That is to say, from a Python box in your Choregraphe behavior, and according to [the documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/software/choregraphe/objects/python_script.html#file-system):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(self.behaviorAbsolutePath(), 'path/to/module'))
```

Please note that since behaviors are running in the process of NAOqi, messing with the `PYTHONPATH` may impact every behavior. So it is good to restore the path when your behavior stops.